# Laravel putFileAs with External URL not working

Tags: laravel

Trying to save an external URL image, to my s3.

But when I use code below, it returns error.

```
      $contents = file_get_contents($url);
      $filename = Str::slug($findproduct->title)."-".uniqid().".".$extension;

      Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('product', $contents, $filename, ['visibility' => 'public']);
```

Here's error:

```
fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given
```

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` is the first function called by `putFileAs` [API Docs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L276).

It attempts to open the `File` supplied as parameter 2 to `putFileAs()`, in your case this is `$contents`. (FWIW, newer versions of Laravel also accept a string as a file path here)

It expects this to be either a `File` or `UploadedFile` object.

[`file_get_contents()` returns a string instead.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Try using this instead:

```
$contents = new File($url);
```